# When should I use ruhig / still?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference, usage, adjective

A friend of mine says that one is typically used for people and the other one is for objects. The dictionary is no help, it gives the same translation for both. Is there a significant difference or are these two fully interchangeable?
When should I use 'ruhig' / 'still'?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Problem is that [*ruhig*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ruhig_starr_leise_beherrscht_still) and [*still*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/still) both have several different meanings. One of the meanings of *ruhig* is *calm* or *serene*, as in the example

> Nun bleib mal ganz ruhig.

In this meaning, *ruhig* can clearly be used for people only, not for objects. Similarly, one meaning of *still* is *guarded* or *reserved*, as in

> Du bist heute so still.

Again, this can only be used for people. So unfortunately there are no clear rules. If you really want to learn to use the two words correctly, I think you'll have to look at many examples and develop a feeling for the meanings. In the two Duden links above you'll find quite a few helpful examples.

But I agree with what others have said here already: don't be afraid of using the "wrong" word. People will still be able to understand you, even if they may pause and think for a second.

Comment: Upvoted and thanks! And an extra thanks for the Duden links, I would have used that site if I had known about it.

Comment: Even more complicated: "Nimm dir ruhig einen Keks, wir haben noch mehr". Here `ruhig` is used to express encuragement rather than meaning to take the cookie quietly.

Comment: @con-f-use: Right, that's a _Partikel_ then, not an adjective. I didn't think of that version of [_ruhig_](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ruhig_getrost_meinetwegen).

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht, wie Du sagen kannst "Sei ruhig" könne nur zu Personen gesagt werden. Ich sehe oft Leute, die derart auf ihren Hund einsprechen. Ebenso kann man nach dem Besuch des Installateurs vermelden, dass die Heizung jetzt endlich ruhig ist. Ebenso kann man feststellen, dass der Papagei heute ganz still ist.

Comment: @user: Lieber user unknown, ich weiß nicht genau, auf welcher Ebene ich auf Deinen Kommentar antworten soll; deshalb versuche ich gleich 3 Varianten. Dein obiger Kommentar ist wahrscheinlich nicht böse gemeint, aber die Formulierung "Ich verstehe nicht, wie Du sagen kannst ...", zusammen mit dem Punktabzug, kam bei mir beim 1. Lesen wie ein Angriff an, nach dem Motto "wie kannst Du bloß ...". Wissen kann ich es natürlich nicht, aber ich vermute, dass es Kommentare wie diese waren, die Gigili damals vertrieben haben.

Comment: 2. Variante: Natürlich kann man zu einem Hund "Sei ruhig" sagen. Aber das ist eine andere Bedeutung von _ruhig_ als _calm_ oder _serene_ (_gelassen_). Man könnte zu seinem Hund auch "Nun bleib mal ganz ruhig" sagen, aber wenn man das tut, behandelt man ihn wie eine Person. Und zu _Objekten_ würde man das sicher nicht sagen - die Heizung ist nicht "jetzt endlich gelassen". (Ähnliches gilt für den stillen Papagei - ist der wirklich _zurückhaltend?_)

Comment: 3. Variante: Ich verstehe nicht, wie Du das nicht verstehen kannst, und wieso Du gleich einen Punktabzug gibst: Ich habe über _Personen_ versus _Objekte_ nachgedacht, und dabei habe ich Tiere ganz vergessen. Das kann doch passieren! Ich finde es gut, dass Du mich auf so etwas hinweist, aber fände es nett, wenn Du mir erstmal die Chance gibst, auf Deinen Hinweis zu reagieren - z.B. mit einer Klarstellung wie in der 2. Variante.

Comment: @Hendrik +1 für das Plädoyer, erst einmal zu reden. Aber mal ganz allgemein gefragt: Ist es wirklich möglich zu erkennen, wer wann wo ein Downvote abgegeben hat?

Comment: @Eugene: Danke `:-)` Nein, man kann das nicht erkennen - ich habe mich da relativ weit aus dem Fenster gelehnt und eine Vermutung wie einen Fakt formuliert.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel Nein, nicht direkt. Man kann es aber erahnen. Oder du überwachst von jedem seine Rep. Du kannst z.b. mal jetzt für diese Woche die Rep's anschauen. user unknown hat 9. Das bedeutet er wurde 1x upgevoted und hat 1x selbst downgevoted. Jetzt rate mal, wo ;p Ahja, klappt nur für Antworten, da bei Fragen keine Rep abgezogen wird.

Comment: PS: Mal so allgemein zu der Diskussion. Das Problem besteht hier - wie so oft -, dass die Frage zu allgemein ist. Es gibt unzählige Anwendungen von ruhig und still, und ich stimme keiner der beiden Antworten zu. Beide haben ihr Wahres, umfassen aber eben nur Teilansichten. Und ich sehe sogar, man kann ruhig/still gleichermaßen für Tiere, Menschen und Objekte verwenden. Die Frage ist nur, auf welche Definition dieser Worte man sich bezieht.

Comment: @Em1: Ich finde die Frage prima so `:-)` Der OP konnte nicht wissen, dass beide Wörter so viele Bedeutungen haben - das hätte er nie erwartet! Ich habe in meiner Antwort bewusst nur einen kleinen Teilaspekt behandelt. Ich wollte vor allem klarmachen, dass die Lage nicht einfach ist und dass es sowohl von _ruhig_ als auch von _still_ Bedeutungen gibt, die nicht auf Sachen angewendet werden können (dass es also keine Regel gibt, auf die der OP gehofft hatte).

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Vielleicht sollten wir die Diskussion gleich in den Chat tragen, denn ich schätze kurz wird es nicht. Ich kann zu einem Menschen "Bleib stehen!" sagen. Das kann ich zu einem Hund auch sagen - vermenschliche ich ihn damit bereits? Soll ich sagen "Flupürps!", weil der Hund die Semantik eh nicht begreift, und nur Tonfall und verbundene Mimik/Gestik interpretiert? Wenn der Hund reagiert, und stehen bleibt, so bleibt er aber doch stehen - auch wenn wir oft eigene Wörter für Tiere haben (essen/fressen, trinken/saufen, Mund/Maul(, Schnabel, ...)), beim Stehenbleiben haben wir es nicht.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Wir reden seltener zu Hunden, insbesondere ich, der keinen hat, und Hunde nicht mag, aber das macht die eine Terminologie nicht zum Original, und die zweite zur Ableitung. Jetzt wird man zu einem Objekt, einem Haus, Stein oder Zug noch viel weniger reden, als zu einem Tier, daher ist die Konstruktion "bleib mal ruhig" gegenüber Objekten selten - das liegt aber nicht am "ruhig", sondern an der Anrede überhaupt. Als jmd. der ein Kartenhaus baut kannst Du eine Konstruktion anflehen "bleib stehen!" oder bei einem Erdbeben vermelden, das Haus sei stehen geblieben.

Comment: Was heißt denn "bleib ruhig" beim Menschen? Dass die Atmung, der Puls ruhig sind. Kein nervöses hin- und herrutschen, kein Brüllen. Nach dem heftigen Beben, bei dem die Regale von den Wänden krachten, und der Tisch durchs Zimmer sprang, war das Haus ebenso plötzlich wieder ruhig. Das ist keine andere Bedeutung von ruhig, sondern die nämliche. Mit `calm` oder `gelassen` zu hantieren ist kein Argument, denn das sind ja andere Wörter, und eben nicht das allgemeinere `ruhig`. Wäre es Absicht, so würde ich von einem Taschenspielertrick sprechen, die Beispiele so auszuwählen, dass jmd. angesprochen

Comment: ... angesprochen wird, um zu belegen, dass es Bedeutungen gibt, die nur Menschen betreffen, aber ich glaube Du hast Dich da selbst hinters Licht geführt. Das Meer ist heute ganz ruhig - und es ist kein Tier. @Downvoten: Ich meine Deine Beispiele stimmen so nicht, sondern sind, um es klar zu sagen, falsch, und gehören daher abgewerted; das ist die vorgesehene Reaktionsform. Das Voting soll die guten Antworten hoch, und die schlechten runter bringen, so ist es gedacht. Nimm es bitte nicht persönlich. Was Gigili betrifft, so sprich mich darauf im Chat an, wenn Du einen Wutausbruch erleben willst.

Comment: @user: Natürlich kann ich zu einem Hund "Bleib stehen!" sagen, ebenso wie zu einem Kartenhaus; ich weiß nicht recht, inwiefern das hier relevant ist. Bei _ruhig_ kann es nicht nur um Ruhe in der Bewegung oder Lautstärke gehen, sondern auch um _psychologische_ Ruhe. (Gut, vielleicht meintest Du das bei "Atmung und Puls".) Wenn Du nun meinst, dass das keine unterschiedlichen Bedeutungen von _ruhig_ sind, sondern ein und dieselbe, dann haben wir anscheinend sehr unterschiedliche Vorstellungen davon, was Sprache ist. Auch wenn der Duden nicht immer recht hat, hier bin ich ganz auf seiner Seite.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Ich sage nicht, dass es nicht unterschiedliche Formen von 'ruhig sein' gibt, so wie es unterschiedliche Straßen gibt. Aber wenn auch die Schloßstraße und die Badstraße unterschiedliche, konkrete Ausprägungen des Phänomens "Straße" sind; der zugrundeliegende Begriff "Straße" meint das selbe. Eine innere Ruhe und die Ruhe im Bett (womöglich unter Alpträumen) sind 2 konkrete Ausformungen von Ruhe - das Wort Ruhe hat aber keine andere Bedeutung, nur weil es sich auf anderes bezieht. Das eine ist eine innere, das andere eine äußere Ruhe.

Comment: @user: Du meinst also, dass _ruhig_ in "ruhige Wohngegend" und "ruhigens Gewissens" die gleiche Bedeutung hat? Dann werden wir nicht einig werden, aber das ist ja auch OK.

Comment: Es ist das gleiche Wort. Es geht nicht etymologisch auf zwei unterschiedliche Sachen zurück. Vielleicht hattest Du noch nie ein unruhiges Gewissen, aber aus Erfahrung kann ich versichern: Es geht dann im Gewissen zu wie auf der Friedrichstraße, freitags um 15:30 Uhr.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3282/discussion-between-user-unknown-and-hendrik-vogt)

Answer (score 6):

Nein.

> Der Motor läuft ruhig, aber nicht still. 
>   Hier bedeutet es regelmäßig, ohne Schlag und Unwucht.

Meist kann man sie aber wechselseitig verwenden:

> Sitz still! Sitz ruhig. 
>   Beim Einschläfern wurde der laute Kläffer schnell ruhig/still.

Eine andere Unterscheidung: Im Sinne von *beruhigt* wird nur ruhig verwendet:

> Ruhig Blut, wir steigen schon nicht ab! (Erhebt keinen Anspruch auf Realismus).

Hier wird nicht *still Blut* gesagt. Blut stillen :) gibt es auch, aber um Verben ging es ja nicht.

Ein Unterschied zwischen Personen oder Sachen ist mir derart unbekannt, dass ich nachfragen muss, wofür man denn angeblich *ruhig*, und wofür *still* verwendet?

Bei einer Uhr mit Pendel/Zeiger würde man nur sagen, dass sie still steht, oder dass der Zug auf freier Strecke still steht. Aber ebenso steht der Marathonläufer mit Seitenstechen bei Kilometer 35 still.

Es gibt auch noch aus dem Wirtschaftsleben den *stillen Teilhaber*, der nicht durch einen ruhigen ersetzt werden kann. Aber ich kann es nur aufzählen, nicht begründen.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you give me a short advice which one to use to be on the safe side? Unfortunately, I am just getting more and more confused... :(

Comment: OK, I revised the question. Anyhow, I up-voted your answer.

Comment: @Ali I agree with uu's Answer, which could of course be extended to dozens of use cases. Unfortunately there isn't a rule of thumb that tells you in one short sentence when to use one or the other. It's possible that some linguists have written in depth about still/ruhig, you would have to look on the web. Of all the mistakes learners of German can make, using _still_ instead of _ruhig_ (or vice versa) would rank very low on the severity scale, in my opinion.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel OK, I understand, I just wanted to understand this but I am even more confused... How about an 80% rule? What if I use still for persons and ruhig for objects? Or I avoid using still altogether?

Comment: @Ali Let's say you're in a German restaurant and you want to order a glass of water. (Unlike in the U.S., there is no complimentary glass of water with your meal.) Then you would say _ein stilles Wasser bitte_. If you get it wrong and say _ein ruhiges Wasser_ by mistake, the waiter damn well better be ready to get you a _Volvic_ without batting an eyelash.

Comment: If it puts you at ease not to have _still/ruhig_ to worry about, then for the time being pick one or the other (it doesn't matter which one). People should know what you mean; if not, they can ask you. What's important for you as a language learner is not to prize correctness above all else. It's fine for you to produce a malformed German sentence as long as people can understand what you want to say. I've seen too many students who were tongue-tied out of fear of making a mistake, perhaps because they were corrected by their teachers every single time.

Comment: As you progress from Intermediate to Advanced (assuming you even want to go that far), that is when you may start aiming for mistake-free German (a goal that most Germans never achieve).

Comment: @EugeneSeidel This question has been blown out of proportion :) Yes, I screw up gender and case in at least every second sentence so still/ruhig is not important. I was just hoping I would get a simple answer but apparently this is not the case.

Answer (score 3):

As other answers already pointed out, there are a lot of different meanings that those words encompass. Since the question does not clarify the context, what we're exactly talking about, I want to respond to the three intersecting definitions.

Before I start, I want to mention one very important fact. Two words are never *fully* interchangeable, otherwise one of those words will die soon. If two words have the same meaning, one is superfluously. That means, there is ever a subtle distinction between words, but, of course, in some contexts they are interchangeable without changing anything in meaning.

So, back to the words. The three meanings which those words share are:

1. noise, sound
2. motion, movement
3. calmness, sedateness

(1) can be used for people, animals and objects. For (2) I'm not completely certain. You can use it for people and animals for sure, but I think it could be possible for objects, too. Though, I don't know any example right now. The latter one can only be used for people, and rarely for animals, too. Most times, when you use the latter one for animals, this is quite related to (2) as you will see in the examples below.

Note, often you will rephrase the sentences using *still* or *ruhig* as nouns (Stille, Ruhe), or using different words with similar meaning (e.g. *leise*). I just want to show a couple of sentences, using both the adjectives and the nouns.

Before I show the examples, I also will mention that there are a lot of examples, where the words *ruhig* or *still* are used figuratively, but I don't want to incorporate them into my answer.

- noise, sound

> Wir haben ruhige Nachbarn.
>
> Nachdem ich mich über sein nerviges Gebrabbel aufgeregt habe, wurde er ganz still.
>
> Der Hamster lief die ganze Nacht im Laufrad. Erst als er Ruhe gab <sub>(ruhig/still war)</sub>, konnte ich einschlafen.
>
> Das Gequietsche vom Laufrad, war nervig. Nachdem ich die Scharniere geölt habe, kehrte wieder Stille ein. <sub>(Here the object is *still*)</sub>

- motion, movement

> Ich konnte vor Nervosität nicht ruhig/still sitzen bleiben.
>
> Bevor die Katze ihre Beute angreift, sitzt sie ganz still da und beobachtet ihr Ziel. <sub>(This also refers to noise)</sub>

- calmness, sedateness

> Ich fühlte eine innere Unruhe, dennoch zeigte ich mich ruhig und gelassen.
>
> Unmittelbar nach dem die Spritze gesetzt wurde, hielt der Hund still. <sub>(Though, the obvious result is that he doesn't move any more)</sub>
>
> Immer wenn Fremde zu Besuch sind, läuft unser Kaninchen unruhig durch den Stall.

Comment: I _almost_ agree with "Two words are never fully interchangeable". In my opinion, extremely rare exceptions do exist, like _Lift_ und _Fahrstuhl_. What do you think?

Comment: Nevertheless, great answer! (I first overlooked that you wrote "which those words share" - that's a very good aspect that wasn't mentioned before.)

Comment: @HendrikVogt Well, *lift* is actually the English word which is *eingedeutscht*. But finally, all these words *Elevator*, *Paternoster*, *Fahrstuhl* and *Aufzug* have a subtle distinction in what they mean, while *Fahrstuhl* und *Aufzug* are often used interchangeable. *Lift* is most common for *Skilift* (again, differs from *Aufzug*), and when you use it for *Personenaufzug*, in my opinion, it is still the English word, and maybe it will get an own connotation with time, it will displace *Aufzug*, or it will disappear from German language, again.

Comment: My bad, I actually meant _Aufzug_ and _Fahrstuhl_ - there I just don't know of any difference. As for the other words, there are indeed differences in meaning and/or usage.

Comment: @HendrikVogt First of all, both words *Aufzug* and *Fahrstuhl* do have at least a second meaning which they do not share with the other word. And moreover, Duden says, that *Fahrstuhl* refers to the cage/cabin of a lift, and - without checking it - I would say that *Fahrstuhl* as *Aufzug* was orginally just a vernacular that moves into usual speech. But, that's just an assumption.

Comment: Well, as for the 2nd meaning of _Fahrstuhl_ I don't quite agree with the Duden - that object I would always call _Rollstuhl_ `:-)` Of course I do agree that there are other meanings of _Aufzug_. I just meant that _Fahrstuhl_ and _Aufzug_ are 100% interchangeable if you refer to a lift. So personally, I'd write "(almost) never _fully_ interchangeable", but I admit this is a really minor nit-pick.